# Angular: fully install service worker before anything else

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm writing a PWA in Angular that needs to be ready to go offline from a single page load. The documentation for the service worker life cycle specifies that the worker is installed but not active immediately: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle

This is by design and can be overruled by calling `clients.claim()`.

The problem with this is that Angular loads the service worker **after** the whole app has been loaded so `claim()` has nothing left to claim. That means the page has to be reloaded and then all the calls are cached (which works in my case) but that seems like a poor user experience.

I see and have tried the following solutions but have gotten stuck on all of them:

- Listen to the install event on the service worker in `app.component.ts` so that I can wait to do my calls that need to be cached until after `claim()` has been called. SwUpdate knows nothing about this event (only updates) and while the following could be an option, it's pointless because the service worker has not been loaded so `navigator.serviceworker` is null: 
  `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.addEventListener('statechange', (stateChangeEvent: Event) => {})`
- Add this to the service worker:
  `self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {})`
  but when testing, I need to tick "update on reload" and so each pageload is going to have an install event, meaning I need to have some way to have it happen only once ever to prevent getting in an infinite loop of reloads. I tried doing this with the localstorage but the service worker has no access to that. Apparently it has access to IndexedDB but I still need to learn how that works and this whole "reload the page on first load" strategy doesn't sit right with me
- Ensure the service worker js is loaded by Angular before anything else. Of course, the install is async so that would mean race conditions with my app. I haven't been able to find how to influence this load order. I tried placing `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/custom-sw.js')` first in `app.module.ts` but that made no difference.

Comment: Apologies, after further digging, I've deleted my answer. Are you using the latest version of the @angular/service-worker?

Comment: the ngsw-worker calls clients.claim() within a generator, when 'activate' is complete

Comment: I am using the latest version, yes. I'm currently using a service worker generated with workbox. Within the service worker itself, I can choose when `claim()` is called so that's not an issue. The question is that Angular installs it with `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/custom-sw.js')` but it still ends up being loaded last. If that could be done first (in the head or something), that could provide more control.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing the call to `skipWaiting()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting)).

`skipWaiting()` when called from the `install` event will move right on to the `activate` event without the user reloading the page.

`clients.claim()` in the `activate` event will claim any clients available at that time.

If you do not call `skipWaiting()`, the `activate` event is not fired until next reload of the page.

Comment: I have the `skipWaiting()`call (it's auto-generated by workbox-build). Any calls made after `claim()` is called are cached. The problem is that the serviceworder js file is loaded after the rest of the resources. I can see that in the network tab of the developer's console.

Comment: Based upon our conversation in a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943206/arent-pwas-user-unfriendly-if-the-service-worker-is-not-immediately-active/58945992), I believe you are asking for behavior that service workers were never intended to provide.

Comment: Yep, maybe I am. Which is why I created the other thread to figure out if I have the right expectations. I am new to it after all.