# Aren't PWAs user unfriendly if the service worker is not immediately active?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I posted another question as a brute-force solution to this one ([Angular: fully install service worker before anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940683/angular-fully-install-service-worker-before-anything-else)) but I thought I'd make a separate one to discuss the use case for when a service worker is used as intended.

According to the service worker life cycle (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle), the SW is installed but it's only active once you then reload the page (you can `claim()` the page but that's only for calls that happen after the service worker is installed). The reasoning is that if and existing version is updated, the old one and the new one do not mix states and caches. I can agree with that decision.

What I have trouble understanding is why it is not immediately active once it is initially installed. Instead, it requires a page reload unless you explicitly define precaching rules in the SW. If you define caching rules with wildcards, it's not possible to precache those so you need the reload.

Given a single page PWA (like Angular), a user will discover the site and browser around on it but the page will never be reloaded during that session. If they then want to use the site offline later, they need to have refreshed or re-opened the tab at least one other time. That seems like a pretty big pitfall to me.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the service worker lifecycle is correct but I do not think the pitfall you mentioned is as severe as you think it is.

If I understand you correctly, the user experience will only be negatively affected if the user loses connectivity during the initial browsing of the page (before the service worker is active) and is missing an offline asset. If this is truly a scenario you want to account for then that offline asset can be pre-cached in the  browser-side javascript. Alternatively, as you mentioned, you can `skipWaiting()` and `claim()` to make the service worker active without the user refreshing the page.

Comment: Losing connectivity is not something I even considered. My experience is that the service worker is not loaded before everything else (eg in Angular) so even if you `skipWaiting()` and `claim()`, it'll be too late.

workbox-build solves some of this by precaching all the essential files but any files that it doesn't have need to be listed individually in the service worker for precaching rather than adding caching routes for urls with wildcards and naturally caching everything on the first page load.

Eg. caching everything in a folder called /images/homepage/*.jpg

Comment: I see now. The behavior you are describing will be after the second load of the page. There is no way for the browser to know which or even if a service worker is needed to cache assets before loading the DOM. Even if there were, the user would be forced to wait until the service worker is parsed, downloaded, executed and in the activated state. 
While the explicit pre-cache file list used in the install event is not the easiest pattern to implement nor maintain, it can provide you what you are looking for on the first reload.

Comment: I guess that the manual precache is the only route to take. At least workbox-build does a lot of that automatically. It still feels to me that something wasn't quite thought through enough with the SW life cycle.